# ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport with Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

Grails is throwing the following error on (run-app):

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "GAME_PLAYER" not found; SQL statement:
alter table game_player drop constraint FK_d6owx50inp7g4imistkxtio05 if exists [42102-176]
```

I'm not using any reserved words in my domain classes, so I'm not sure what's causing it. I've tried cleaning the project and starting over, no matter what I still get the error.

Domain classes:

```
package highscoresservice

import grails.rest.*


class Game {

    static hasMany = [players:Player]
    String gameName

}

package highscoresservice

class Player {

    String playerName
    int playerScore

    static constraints = {
    } 

}
```

Bootstrap:

```
import highscoresservice.Game
import highscoresservice.Player

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        new Game(gameName:"Agame").addToPlayers(new Player(playerName:"bob", playerScore: 12)).save()


    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using. And What do you have specified for dbCreate = "xx" in Datasource.groovy. The error simply means hibernate can not find the join table

Comment: This is harmless, see [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23858953/160313) for a dialect that prevents the error messages.